# How can I use DD-WRT to resolve multiple hostnames to one IP address?

Tags: networking, dns, lan, dd-wrt

### **How can I set up DD-WRT (or anything else) such that I can have various hostnames all point to various different Nginx projects on the same local server?**

I have a wifi router with DD-WRT.

I'm a software engineer developing multiple different sites on my local server (Nginx on Windows 10).

My Windows `hosts` file specifies various hostnames, and my Nginx config points them to certain directories on my machine, `ryandesk.local`.

I very often want to access these local websites using an iPhone on my wifi LAN.

The only way I know how to set up my Nginx config, Windows `hosts` file, and DD-WRT is such that my iPhone can reach *one* of the local sites.

I can either type in the local IP of my server, or I could visit `http://ryandesk.local` (since that's the computer name on the network), or I could visit `http://ryandesk.xyz` (assuming I set up a static lease in DD-WRT as [as described in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857012/470749)).

The Nginx config specifies which local site is "default" and will be displayed.

I want *all* of my local sites to be accessible from my iPhone, though (each with their own hostname).

I'd also *prefer* answers that don't bother with ports. (It seems like bookmarks and other stuff all stays simpler if I'm not messing with multiple ports.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page on the DD-WRT wiki](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_Local_Network#2.29_Additional_DNS_Options), you should be able to point multiple domain names at a single IP address by adding multiple domain names in an `address` option statement in the "Additional DNSMasq options" box. For example, this DNSMasq option…

```
address=/example.com/foo.com/bar.com/192.168.1.201
```

…should cause "example.com", "foo.com", and "bar.com" to all resolve to 192.168.1.201.

Comment: According to what wiki page (maybe you meant to paste a link)? I found https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server but couldn't find what you're talking about. And I tried a configuration based on your example, and it seemed to have no effect. I'm excited about you answer, though, because it looks like it's probably on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I think you meant this page: https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_Local_Network And it worked! The only step that I hadn't taken was switch my iPhone into "Airplane mode" temporarily (to flush the DNS cache) and then switch back onto wifi. It worked. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Ryan Oops, sorry I forgot to paste in the link before. I've fixed it now. Yes, the second link you found was the one I had meant to link to. Glad you found it and it worked! :-)

Comment: @Ryan note any local DNS you might run can do the same thing.  you're just mapping names to IPs -- the DNS looks up the name and returns the associated IP.  i believe you could accomplish the same effect in DNSMasq with multiple `address` definitions that end in the same IP (works in my DDWRT, no guarantees).

Comment: @Ryan also note it might be convenient for your purpose to set a catch-all: `address=/web.local/.web.local/192.168.1.201` will act as a *wildcard* -- DNSMasq will give the same IP for any new address that ends in `.web.local` -- so `foo.web.local`, `bar.web.local`, and `baz.web.local` all get answered without additional setup.

Comment: @quixotic Wow, that is really good to know and will definitely be convenient! Thanks!